# Error Reporting in WPF app

Tags: c#, error-handling, wpf

I want to add an error reporting feature to my WPF app. I have the view for it created; I just need to know when to call it. I am used to web development and this is my first WPF app.

```
public static void Get<T>(Func<T> func, Action<BaseResult<T>> callback, bool report = false){

    BaseResult<T> result;

    try { 

        result = new BaseResult<T>(func()); 
    } 

    catch (Exception ex){

        if (report) new ErrorWindow(ex.Message).Show();

        result = new BaseResult<T>(false, ex.Message);

        
    }

    callback(result);
}
```

The `BaseResult` class stores the result if the call was successful and an error message if it isn't. Sometimes I don't want to report the result of the call to an error screen, sometimes I just want to know if the call was successful.

1. Does this violate Single Responsibility Principle?
2. This can't be the best way of implementing this. Has anyone done this before? My way seems overly complicated.

Comment: composition per se does not violate SRP. In fact composition is a natural result of good SRP across the app class' design. Pass-through methods for composed-object methods is also SRP compliant.  However implementing things that are rightfully composed-object functionality is SRP violation, even if least knowledge principle integrity is maintained for client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's split your logic into two methods

```
public static void Get<T>(Func<T> func, Action<BaseResult<T>> callback, bool report = false)
{
    var result = GetSafe(func, report);

    if (report && result.IsFault) 
    {
        new ErrorWindow(ex.Message).Show();
    }
        
    callback(result); //does not fit here nicely
}

private static BaseResult<T> GetSafe<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    try 
    { 
        return new(func()); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new(false, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

- The `GetSafe`'s responsibility is to execute the provided user delegate and map the execution outcome accordingly
- The `Get`'s responsibility is to call `GetSafe` and notify user about failure

And that's where the `callback` does not fit in.

### Change return type

```
public static BaseResult<T> Get<T>(Func<T> func, bool report = false)
{
    var result = GetSafe(func, report);

    if (report && result.IsFault) 
    {
        new ErrorWindow(ex.Message).Show();
    }

    return result;
}

private static BaseResult<T> GetSafe<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    try 
    { 
        return new(func()); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new(false, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

With this approach the consumer of the `Get` API does not have to provide an *"execution outcome handler"* rather than they can do the handling by their own.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful.